# Cx_freeze exe failing to completely import docx

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze, python-docx

I have a pretty hefty python script that I'm trying to cx_freeze, however when I run the executable file I keep getting the same error and it appears to be related to the docx module.

I'm using Python 3.3.5 with docx 0.7.6-py33 on a Windows 8.1 machine.

This is my setup script.

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

includefiles = ['logo.ico','db.db','dbloc.bin']
includes = []
excludes = []
packages = ['tkinter','docx','sys', 'sqlite3', 'os', 'hashlib', 'random', 'uuid', 'base64', 'tempfile', 'win32api',
            'winreg', 'ntplib', 'winsound', 'time', 'csv', 'webbrowser', 'inspect','datetime', 'decimal', 'ctypes',
            'win32com.client','operator']

exe = Executable(
# what to build
   script = "NEPOS.py",
   initScript = None,
   base = 'Win32GUI',
   targetName = "Nepos.exe",
   copyDependentFiles = True,
   compress = True,
   appendScriptToExe = True,
   appendScriptToLibrary = True,
   icon = 'Icon.ico'
)

setup(
    name = "MyProgram",
    version = "1.0.0",
    description = 'Description',
    author = "Joe Bloggs",
    author_email = "123@gmail.com",
    options = {"build_exe": {"excludes":excludes,"packages":packages,
      "include_files":includefiles}},
    executables = [exe]
)
```

This is the error I'm getting.

[image]

It looks like it is having trouble finding methods that belong to docx, but my source code calls `import docx` and it is listed as a dependent module in the setup file so I'm not sure why they aren't being included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a LOT of messing about I've finally cracked this. The `docx` module is dependent on `lxml`. Even though the raw `.py` file runs perfectly fine with just `docx` imported, when cx_freezing you need to explicitly state the dependency by adding `lxml` to the packages.

Comment: It was including part of lxml, but it missed another part that it needed to include.

Comment: What I've also noticed is that the docx templates aren't included in the `library.zip` created by cx_freeze. Editing that library post freeze gives me more errors, so I moved the template (which is just a blank docx file) in the working directly and explicitly open it, rather than just `document()`.

Comment: Hi, i know i'm late, but how did you do that? @I_do_python

Comment: Neverming, i solved it copying the docx `document.py` module inside my function (instead of using `Document()` and solved it. Thanks by posting your solution :)

Comment: @aaossa: how did you do it? I am struggling with the same problem right now